# How to drop the night feeding for a 3-month-old?

Tags: feeding, bottle-feeding

I am looking for some wisdom. My little one is 3 months and feeds 6 bottles a day at 150 ml. We feed her at 10 pm, 2 am and 6 am rigidly every day and the remainder during daytime when she requires.

She is in bed from 7 pm-6.30 am. She mostly dream feeds 10 pm and 2 am, but I have to change her mid-feed (so she isn't 100% asleep) as she gets so wet after 4 hours. The other times she wakes up 5 minutes before my alarm, so she is definitely hungry!

I am looking for encouraging ways to eventually drop the 2 am feed. I'm not desperate to do this, as she is stirring only at 2 and then about 6 am, but I do need to regain my own full-night's sleep where possible.

She was 6 lb. at birth and 3 weeks early so I don't want to be too hard on her as she is catching up still at 11 lb. 8 oz.

Comment: Each of ours were about 2 years old before we could escape night feedings. For sanity, I hope you have better luck. Our transition key was that I, their dad, took over night company so feeding wasn't a natural option. Remove mom from the night routine and they figured it out within a week or two.

Comment: I wonder if you could have a nap with baby during the day?  Even if it's short, that can be extremely helpful.  - - -  By the way, your pediatrician would probably be a good person to ask whether your baby is still needing that meal as part of the catching up from prematurity.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm a first time mum...guess I am just optimistically anticipating a full night sleep. Think my only chance is packing LO off to Grandma for a night!I will discuss with my health visitor to see if they can suggest anything. I don't feel like I need to nap would just be good to have unbroken sleep! Perhaps the dummy idea is worth a try, they say to dream feed so that they don't wake up for the feed specifically but I think she's currently on an internal alarm to wake up at 2am! Will see how she goes as she develops over the next couple of months.  Thank you all x

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for your question! I made some minor edits to help make your question easier to read, and hopefully attract more answers for you.

Comment: "I don't feel like I need to nap" -- you might want to try it a couple of times.  I found it soo helpful.  And Sarah Bernhardt apparently found the power nap to be extremely energizing.

Comment: You might be luckier than you realize.  Your baby is not waking you up again at 4 am, two hours after the last meal!

Answer (score 1):

My son is 6 months and didn't stop his night feedings until 5 months. He is 16 lbs now was 6 lbs when he was born. I bathe him and put him to bed no later than 8:30. If he does wake up I put his binky in his mouth and he falls right back to sleep. That's how I broke his night feedings.